# Как работать с расширением для браузера selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Я установил для selenium расширение vpn-free.pro. Браузер загружает и включает расширение сразу. Как мне открыть автоматически расширение и поставить другую страну? Сразу включается Великобритания, а мне нужна Россия.
Вот код

```
def parse_sberbank(mass: list):
"""
Функция работы с сбермаркет
:param mass:
:return:
"""

Map_coordinates = dict({
    "latitude": 55.74507757945719,
    "longitude": 37.61949735504636,
    "accuracy": 100
})

result = []

now = datetime.datetime.now()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) "
                     "Chrome/106.0.0.0 YaBrowser/22.11.0.2419 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36")
options.add_extension(r"C:\freelacne\project_parse_eat\parse_site\freevpn.crx")
# options.add_argument('--headless')

try:

    for item in mass:
        word_ = -1
        word = item[2].split("\r\n")

        while len(word) - 1 != word_:
            word_ += 1
            with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as browser:

                browser.execute_cdp_cmd("Emulation.setGeolocationOverride", Map_coordinates)
                browser.get(item[3])
```

Comment: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/test-chrome-extensions-in-selenium

Comment: Проще будет использовать прокси, которые будут задаваться также через options.